# How does one say "Mensch" en français?

Tags: anglais, choix-de-mot, allemand

The German masculine noun Mensch
means a human being, as opposed to Mann or Frau (man or woman).
Thus "ein guter Mensch" means a good human being.

In German, this same noun has an additional vocative sense,
as a familiar form of address.
This occurs in Alfred Döblin's "Berlin Alexanderplatz".
I think either Eugene Jolas or Michael Hofmann renders it as "kid" when
Franz Biberkopf calls one of his girlfriends "Mensch."
And  when a woman speaks to a woman (when Eva speaks to Sonja), the translators sometimes
render it as "girl" and sometimes with Sonja's name:

> Döblin p 303: Du bist doch schwul, Mensch.
>
> Jolas p 379: Sure, you're queer, Sonia.
>
> Hoffman p 263: You're queer, girl.

In ancient Greek, we have something similar.
The noun ἄνθρωπος (hence "anthropology") means a human being as opposed to ἀνήρ man and γυνή woman. For instance, Matthew 12.36 is translated in the King James as
"... every idle word that men shall speak ..." whereas the word is ἄνθρωπος,
meaning human beings.

In English, via Yiddish, Mensch means (per online Oxford English Dictionary):

> In Jewish usage: a person of integrity or rectitude; a person who is morally just, honest, or honourable.

A famous instance of this usage occurs in Billy Wilder's film "The Apartment."

In contemporary French, what words capture these senses of "Mensch"?

Comment: This question is not well-suited for this site for two reasons. It's too broad: it covers three very different sets of meanings, which just happen to have a common spelling in German. You haven't said which references you've consulted and in what way they are not satisfactory. Beware that none of the three answers posted at this time are good: they're all missing common words or explaining nuances poorly.

Comment: From times to times you can see, _Homme_, with a capital letter. When that's the case it means human an not man. In regards with the current idea to have French more inclusive towards gender, though, this way of expressing it is highly questionable.

Answer (score 3):

There is a couple of ways to name a human being in French a gender neutral way like ***une personne*** or ***un être humain*** but you can't use them to address someone.

***Toi*** or ***vous*** might be used in a dialogue.

"Ein guter Mensch" might translate to ***une bonne personne*** or ***quelqu'un de bien***. They work whatever the gender of the person.

The Jewish usage also looks like ***honnête homme*** which obviously isn't gender neutral but ***une personne intègre*** and both of the expressions suggested above could be used.

Answer (score 2):

As a literary example, where word *Mensch* in its American/Yiddish sense could be appropriate, one could give [The Story of a Real Man](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histoire_d%27un_homme_v%C3%A9ritable), translated in French as [Histoire d'un homme veritable](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histoire_d%27un_homme_v%C3%A9ritable), and in German [Die Geschichte vom wahren Menschen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Geschichte_vom_wahren_Menschen). I think *Real man / homme veritable / wahren Menschen* here is used in the meaning closest to what is meant by *Mensch* in American English, although perhaps in less colloquial register (or perhaps simply because it is a literal translation from the Russian original.)

I might need some help from French speakers for my other example: in film [The Counterfeiters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Counterfeiters_(2007_film)) / [Les Faussaires](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Faussaires_(film,_2007)) / [Die Fälscher](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_F%C3%A4lscher) a Nazi guard gives the following epitaph to one of the prisoners: *"Er war ein Jude, aber er war auch ein Mensch."* (*"He was a Jew, but he was a real man."*) Unfortunately, I have never seen this film in French, and it seems not sufficiently well-known to pull out quotes from the internet. Perhaps, someone who has seen it in French could advise me on how *Mensch* was rendered in this context.

**Remark:**
My quote from counterfeiters might be unexact. According to [this link](https://subslikescript.com/movie/The_Counterfeiters-813547), the English version is *"A Jew... but he died like a man!"*

Answer (score -1):

There does not  exist in  French an equivalent term such as "man" in English or "Mensch" in German as used  as appositive terms in the singular. Some terms have somewhat similar  connotations but they are  not  used often and tend to  be used in a  haughty  manner that borders on the vulgar. They will  not translate  every time  the two terms « man » and « Menschn ».

> - collègue (*can be haughty*)
> - copain (*popular, can be  haughty or jocular*)
> - camarade
> - les gars (*popular, used most  often, free of connotations  but for groups of young or middle age men only*)
> - les mecs (*popular, used most  often, free of connotations  but for groups of young or middle age men only, considered  vulgar by some people although  much used nowadays*)

*A few examples of use, but translated in English  only (not  proficient in German)*

- Dis copain  tu peux pas regarder où   tu marches ?  (*not  polite*)
  Man! Can't you watch where you tread?
- Allez les  gars, on y va !
  *Let's go men !* (*fairly  good   rendering in this case*)
- Allez les  mec, on y va !
  *Let's go men !* (*fairly  good   rendering in this case, considered   vulgar  by some  people, although much used nowadays*)

---

There are several additional  restrictions  on  the use of  these terms.   Most  importantly, « copain », «  les gars » ou les « mecs » can't be used for women. (see [**user jlliagre's comment**](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/51131/how-does-one-say-mensch-en-fran%c3%a7ais/51133?noredirect=1#comment106075_51133)).

Comment: *Copain*, *les gars* ou *les mecs* ne peuvent pas être utilisés quand on s'adresse à une ou plusieurs femmes.